# Using Cucumber to test RubyCAS-Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara, cas

I have a very small freshly made Rails 3 application. I am using the RubyCAS-Client gem for Rails to authenticate against our CAS server. The CAS client is working as I am able to log into and out of my web application.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'nifty-generators'
# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rubycas-client'
gem 'rubycas-client-rails', :git => "git://github.com/zuk/rubycas-client-rails.git"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'webrat'
end
```

Here is my Cucumber stuff:

```
# feature file

Feature: Manage generic_pages
  In order to view pages that are in the base controller(generic)
  I want to visit them and see that they work

  Scenario: Visit the home page
    Given I am on the home page
    Given I am logged in
    Then I should see "Submit a nomination"
    And I should see "Nominee's name"
    And I should see "What are you nominating them for?"
    And I should see "Why are you nominating them for this award?"

# cas-client steps

Given /^I am logged_in$/ do
  CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter.fake("homer")
end
```

The error I get is:

```
Given I am logged_in                                                                        # features/step_definitions/casclient_steps.rb:1
      uninitialized constant CASClient::Frameworks (NameError)
      ./features/step_definitions/casclient_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am logged_in$/'
      features/manage_nominations.feature:9:in `Given I am logged_in'
```

All of the steps pass( if I remove all of the Cas login requirements). If I add the casclient gem's 'require' lines the "logged in" step passes as well, but then the rest of the steps fail. For some reason it is as if Cucumber is not loading the proper gems from the Gemfile and so the CASClient module is not available to its environment. Fudging the require lines in is like an end run around the problem but it doesn't actually fix anything other than the immediate error.

The fake filter is how you are supposed to test this using Cucumber and its ilk. I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: thanks a lot, you let me know how to mock the login for CAS: `CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter.fake("homer")`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using gem 'rubycas-client-rails' you should use:

RubyCAS::Filter.fake('homer')

No need to have the require 'casclient/frameworks/rails/filter'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, and I managed to solve it by manually doing

```
require 'casclient/frameworks/rails/filter'
```